# « S'il ne connaît pas des gens qui sont comme ça, c'est qu'il est off » : sens ou synonyme de « off » dans ce contexte etc. ?

Tags: sens, anglais, québec, anglicismes, emprunts

> Quant aux remarques de Stéphane Dompierre qui affirme ne reconnaître
> aucun des personnages de C.A. [un [téléroman](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.A.)] dans son cercle
> élargi, Louis Morissette répond : « S'il ne connaît pas de gens qui
> sont comme ça, c'est qu'il est ***off***. Tout le monde connaît un petit
> couple de banlieue qui est sur le pilote automatique. » (Hugo Dumas,
> [LaPresse](https://numerique.banq.qc.ca/patrimoine/details/52327/2204439), 2006, p.4, en italiques dans le texte)

J'ai employé le mot anglais [*off*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/off) récemment à quelques reprises pour signifier la même chose dans un contexte similaire. À ne pas confondre avec être *off* pour signifier « ne pas travailler » en français du Québec (« je suis *off* aujourd'hui » ; en congé).

- Cette manière d'employer l'emprunt *off* est-elle unique au Québec et
  qu'est-ce que ça signifie précisément ? ou ;
- En s'appuyant sur le contexte, quel en serait un synonyme ?

Answer (score 2):

- *Off* dans ce cas vient de *off-kilter* (qui fournit pas mal de sens de *off*, *pourri* par exemple, ou *to be off one's game*.) Ça veut dire la même chose en anglais, cet emprunt.  Je ne sais plus si c'est unique au Québec.
- Des synonymes : Il n'est pas dans le coup, sur la touche, il n'est pas à la page, ce qu'il dit est [à côté de la plaque](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A0%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20la%20plaque).  Plus extrême : il est malade.

> kilter
> n   out of kilter    détraqué(e)     → He thinks things are entirely out of kilter in society. We misplace our values.       →
> everything was upside down and out of kilter.       to throw sth out
> of kilter    détraquer qch

Comment: Enfin *off kilter* vient des 1600s donc c'est assez naturel que *off* est ce qui en reste.   *Off the wall* est plus moderne, des années 60s-70s, mais un peu différent à mon avis. 
En tout cas *off* a le même sens, non ?  Très intéressant de le retrouver en français.  La dérivation de la préposition *of* avec de l'emphase date du 13 c. de Old English.

Comment: Pis de nos jours personne ne sait ce que ça veut dire, *kilter* !  Très perdu en étymologie.

Comment: L'emprunt ne date certainement pas du 17e. Mais oui, vu que souvent les composés avec _off_ ont comme point commun de signifier « à l'extérieur » ou « hors », on perçoit le sens quand on possède bien la langue anglaise ou si on lit la phrase comme si elle était en anglais et qu'on voit ce qu'on dirait spontanément dans cette position-là dans la phrase. C'est un sens proche de _out of the loop_ je pense. Je pensais à _off-beat_ ou à _off_ comme antonyme de _in_. Je pense que c'est très proche de la valeur pure de l'adverbe/adj./prép., 20e mais par quel chemin exact on en arrive là, je sais pas.